# How to create capital letter row for a list of names in an ASP Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I'm using an asp repeater to display a list of names and I want to display the current letter as a type of grouping header, like in an index page.

The data is sorted alphabetically before binding, but i'm finding it difficult to insert the 'A' and 'B' before the names are displayed.

Comment: Have you tried sorting the data in your datasource ?

Comment: yes i can do the sorting. the problem i'm facing is how to insert the 'A' and 'B' before the names are displayed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Panel control to your ItemTemplate with visibility set to False. When you are binding the repeater (assuming you are subscribing to the `ItemDataBound` event), run a check to see if the first letter has changed. If it has, set the panel's visibility to true and print out the letter.

Let me know if you need some example code.

**EDIT: EXAMPLE CODE**

For clarity sake, "AlphaHeaders" is what we will call the "A", "B", "C" letters that we want to display

**aspx code**

The Repeater will look like so:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater id="rptRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptNames_OnItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel id="pnlAlphaHeader" runat="server" visible="False">
               <tr><td><asp:Label id="lblAlphaHeader" runat="server" /></td></tr>
            </asp:Panel>
            <tr><td><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" /></td></tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

**aspx.cs code**

First, you need a variable that holds the current AlphaHeader:

```
private string _AlphaHeaderCurrent = String.Empty;
```

Then you will do your work on the repeater's `OnItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void rptNames_OnItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if ((e.ItemType==ListItemType.Item) || (e.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) {
      string name = e.Item.DataItem("Name").ToString();
      //check if the first letter of the current name is new. If it is new, we print out the header
      if(!name.StartsWith(this._AlphaHeaderCurrent)) {
         this._AlphaHeaderCurrent = name.SubString(1);                               
         ((Panel)e.ItemFindControl("pnlAlphaHeader")).Visible = true;
         ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblAlphaHeader")).Text = the._AlphaHeader;
      }
      ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName")).Text = name;          
   }
}
```

Comment: can you give some code example..that would be really helpfull

Answer (score 2):

You sort before you bind.

That is, bind the sorted result set.

Without seeing the values you have, however, it is not possible to tell exactly how to do so.

---

Update - from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834335/how-to-sort-in-asp-repeater/14834366#comment20785324_14834366), I would say you need to change your binding source to something like `Dictionary<string,IList<string>>`.

With such a structure, you could bind by key (sorted) and sublist (secondary sort).

Comment: i have sorted it before binding.I have no problem in displaying the sorted result in 1 go,the problem is how to insert those 'A' and 'B' in above the names.

Comment: Insert to your source and then rebind?

Comment: @Rain - That's not clear from your questions - edit it to make sure you're highlighting that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort your data before bind it to the repeater.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested repeaters (repeater inside repeater). Like category and subcategory.
In first repeater you can list all your names and make a condition starts with A. Then in sub repeater you can show all names. You will also use itemdatabound event to bind second repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptFirstLetters" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptChars_OnItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>"<%#Eval("letters") %>"
        <asp:Repeater id="rptNames" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("names") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>         
    </div> // bind all letters
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a nice way of doing this to be honest, repeaters generally result in ugly code I've found. The hierarchical approach from kad1r is probably the nicest if you can set it up, but there are alternatives, depending on your implementation details; I kind of prefer this in some ways as it keeps the markup very clean, and as I have a non-programmer design guy that is a plus for me.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Src="test.CODE.cs" Inherits="test_Page" %>
<asp:Repeater ID="TestRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder Visible='<%# Eval("IsFirstInGroup") %>' runat="server">
            <strong><%# Eval("Initial") %></strong><br/>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <%# Eval("Name") %><br/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class test_Page : Page
{
        protected Repeater TestRepeater;

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
                base.OnInit(e);

                String[] names = new String[] 
                {        
                        "Alpha, John",
                        "Altman, Mary", 
                        "Asher, Cyril",
                        "Bachman, Turner",
                        "Beta, Rob",
                        "Bexman, Norah",
                        "Clark, Freddy"
                };

                List<_DispItem> l = new List<_DispItem>();

                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                        l.Add(new _DispItem() { Name = names[i], IsFirstInGroup = (i == 0 || names[i - 1][0] != names[i][0]) });

                TestRepeater.DataSource = l;
                TestRepeater.DataBind();
        }

        private class _DispItem
        {
                public String Name { get; set; }
                public String Initial { get { return Name.Substring(0, 1); } }
                public bool IsFirstInGroup { get; set; }
        }
}
```